# Definition of $C^{m,k/2}$-capacity of a point.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, potential-theory

I hve come across the following notation and a new term $C^{m,k/2}$-capacity of a point. I'd appreciate some reference, where I can find the definition and relevant theory.

Comment: Context would help, such as the name of the paper or book you saw this in, and where in that paper/book in case someone wants to look for it. This is because notation like this can vary. That said, maybe a google search for ["generalized capacity" + Sobolev](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22generalized+capacity%22+Sobolev), or some such, will turn up something.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro : I found this during my interaction with a math Professor, where he suggested me to use this concept to simplify a proof that I had written. Unfortunately I couldn't get back to him.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro :  It was related to Sobolev space.

Comment: I don't know much about this topic, but I do know that multiple subscripts and/or superscripts often show up on symbols for capacity notions that are associated with Sobolev spaces, which is why I used "Sobolev" in the search.

Answer (score 0):

The $C^{m,k/2}$ capacity of a point $x \in \mathbb R^d$ might be the number:
$$
\inf\{ \|\varphi\|_{W^{m,k/2}(\mathbb R^d)} \mid \varphi \ge 1 \text{ in an open superset of } \{x\}\}.
$$
(Often, this is raised to the power $k/2$).
Note that this number does not depend on $x$, since everything is translation invariant.

For further reading, I would suggest the books

- Nonlinear Potential Theory of Degenerate Elliptic Equations by Juha Heinonen, Tero Kipelainen, Olli Martio
- Function Spaces and Potential Theory by  Adams, David R., Hedberg, Lars I.

Comment: Interestingly, I have a copy of Heinonen/Kipelainen/Martio's book and I looked at it yesterday for this question, but I felt that I didn't know enough about the subject to recommend looking at their book for this question.